# Html Dropdownlist built with jquery not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code to dynamically build a dropdown list on the IE10 browser, depending on values retrieved from database

```
function buildOption(container, namepreface, id, val, txt) {
    var obj = $("<option />", { id : namepreface + id, value : val, text : txt});
    $("#"+ container).append(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

here is the html it generated, which I copied from the F12, DOM Explorer

```
<li>
    <span class="div120RAlgn inlineblock">
        <label for="CostCenter">Cost Center:</label>
    </span>
    <span class="editor-field-alLw220">
        <select id="CostCenter">
            <option id="costcenter_0" value="0"> </option>
            <option id="costcenter_3" value="3">All</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</li>
```

However the first time I click the drop down arrow, I get an empty box, like it isn't initialized.

[image]

When I click on it again, it appears as it should

[image]

Anybody have any ideas as to what is going on and how to fix it?  This problem is consistent regardless of what the values are and regardless the number of options in the list

This segment is in in the document ready function

```
$("#Region").change(function (e) {
    loadRegionLocations(e.currentTarget);
});
$("#Location").change(function (e) {
    loadLocationsCostCenters(e.currentTarget);
});
```

And these are the two methods called

```
function loadRegionLocations(tar) {
    $("#CostCenter").empty();
    $("#Location").empty();
    buildOption("Location", "location_", 0, 0, ' ');
    var selloc = searchArgsForObjLst($(tar).val(), "REGIONID", "LOCATIONNAME", locationlst);
    $.each(selloc, function (i, o) {
        var c = buildOption("Location", "location_", o.LOCATIONID, o.LOCATIONID, o.LOCATIONNAME);
        c.data("REGIONID", o.REGIONID);
    });
}


function loadLocationsCostCenters(tar) {
    $("#CostCenter").empty();
    buildOption("CostCenter", "costcenter_", 0, 0, ' ');
    var selcc = searchArgsForObjLst($(tar).val(), "LOCATIONID", "COSTCENTERNAME", costcenterlst);
    $.each(selcc, function (i, o) {
        var c = buildOption("CostCenter", "costcenter_", o.COSTCENTERID, o.COSTCENTERID, o.COSTCENTERNAME);
        c.data("REGIONID", o.REGIONID);
        c.data("LOCATIONID", o.LOCATIONID);
    });
}
```

Comment: can you post dropdown click event code? It will be more helpful to check what went wrong?

Comment: fiddle would be even better :)

Comment: Ive added the requested events.  I can't run this through fiddle yet, I'm debugging in VS2012 and using IIS Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have found a solution to the above problem.  At least I added the code below and so far its been working.

```
$.fn.redraw = function () {
$(this).each(function () {
    var redraw = this.offsetHeight;
});
```

};

Then in the methods where I build the options, I added a call to that method, like so

```
    function loadLocationsCostCenters(tar) {
    $("#CostCenter").empty();
    buildOption("CostCenter", "costcenter_", 0, 0, ' ');
    var selcc = searchArgsForObjLst($(tar).val(), "LOCATIONID", "COSTCENTERNAME", costcenterlst);
    $.each(selcc, function (i, o) {
        var c = buildOption("CostCenter", "costcenter_", o.COSTCENTERID, o.COSTCENTERID, o.COSTCENTERNAME);
        c.data("REGIONID", o.REGIONID);
        c.data("LOCATIONID", o.LOCATIONID);
    });
    **$("#CostCenter").redraw();**
}
```